# When using description/item, long item names add and extra empty line

Tags: description, white-space

When using description/item, long item names add and extra space.
I would like to know if there is a way to remove the extra empty lines that appear after items named "This item name is longer than some value...........................................".

Here are the anonymised file codes.

Main.tex

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
    }

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}

\title{Subsubtitle}
\author{Name}
\date{2020}

\begin{document}
    \input{Pages/TitlePage.tex}
    \tableofcontents

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{Subsubtitle}
\rfoot{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{Glossaire}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\vskip 0.5cm
\textit{Some date}

\begin{description}
\item[[This item name is short)]\index{item1} \hfill \\There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect.

\item[This item name is longer than some value...........................................]\index{item2}\hfill \\Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph?

\item[[This item name is short)]\index{item1} \hfill \\There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect. There is no space after item name and it is what Is expect.

\item[This item name is longer than some value...........................................]\index{item2}\hfill \\Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph? Why do I get a space before this paragraph?

\end{description}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Pages/TitlePage.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

    \HRule \\[0.9cm]
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{\Huge Big title}\\[1cm]
        \textsc{\LARGE Subtitle}\\[1.5cm]
        \textsc{\Large Subsutitle}\\[1.5cm]
    \end{center}
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \vfill

    \begin{center} \large
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r @{}}
            \ & \\
            \ & \\
            \ & \\
            \  & Some label : some value\\
            \  & Some label : some value
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\blankpage
```

Comment: Will your long item names possible be longer than  linewidth?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a defined "linewidth" value somewhere and how I could know it.
One of the real titles that gets the extra line is longer than paragraph width but short enough to be display one on line on the page.
Another real title that gets the problem is exactly the width of paragraph (maybe a half character longer, this is hard to tell).

Comment: Try loading `enumitem` and using  `\begin{description}[style=unboxed]. It might be enough. Other than that, a possibility would be to redefine the `\descriptionlabel``  command

Comment: Thank you. Just adding \usepackage{enumitem} solved the issue for the shorter name, [style=unboxed] solved for the longer one.

(I you write this as anwser I could select as solution.)

Comment: I don't think it's worth writing an answer. I'm sure there are already other similar answers (but I don't know where).